# Conditions when solutions of $\dot{x} = f(x)$ exist for all time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am reading the following textbook:

`Introduction to Applied Nonlinear Dynamical Systems and Chaos` by Wiggins 
p.92 (top)

Consider $$\dot{x} = f(x)$$ where $f(x)$ is $C^r$, $r\geq 1$, on some open set $U\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose that the solutions exist for all time (Leave it as an exercise to make the necessary modifications when solutions exist only on finite time intervals).

> My problem is what are the conditions to make solutions exist for all time.

Consider and example:  $$\dot{x} = x^2, \ \ \ \ x\in \mathbb{R}$$

the solution through $x_0$ at $t = 0$ is $$x(t,0,x_0) = \frac{-x_0}{x_0t - 1}$$

this solution (trajectory) does not exist for all time, since it becomes infinite at $t = 1/x_0$.

So what are the conditions to make solution exist for all time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usual conditions for the infinite existence of solutions of $\dot x=f(x)$ are restrictions to linear growth like
$$
|\dot x|=|f(x)|\le C(1+|x|)
$$
or
$$
\frac12\frac{d}{dt}|x|^2=|x^T\dot x|=|x^Tf(x)|\le C(1+|x|^2)
$$
which impose an exponential bound on the growth of solutions. The solution of the corresponding differential inequalities is with the Grönwall lemma.

---

These are not the only conditions, only the relatively easy ones. If the vector field $f(x)$ points inwards on the boundary of a bounded set $U$, all solutions are restricted to $U$ and thus bounded and exist for all positive times. This looks geometrically simple but can be hard to establish

Comment: How do you relate that to the ODE ?

Comment: For your second condition, it looks like the example $\dot{x} = x^2$ in my problem satisfies this; however, it does not have solution for all time?

Comment: @sleevechen : No, $x^Tf(x)=x^3$ grows faster than $|x|^2$.

Comment: Thanks I see. It looks a bit like the definition of Lipshitz continuity.

Comment: BTW, these are sufficient conditions?

Comment: Yes. I do not know of necessary conditions, ODE can have a vast variety of behaviors. You can only select classes of nice ones.